# Existence of a invertible Matrix AB

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove or Disprove:
>
> There exists $A\in M_{2 \times 5}(\mathbb{R})$ and $B\in M_{5 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $AB=I_2$

I know this result : If $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix and $B$ is an $n \times m$ matrix with $m>n$, then $AB$ is not invertible. How about this one?

Comment: Denoting the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^5$ as $e_i$'s and $f_j$'s respectively, define $A: \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^5$ by $e_i \mapsto f_i$, and $B: \mathbb{R}^5 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ by $f_i \mapsto e_i, i=1,2$ and $f_j \mapsto 0, j \geq 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to think about it.

If $A$ is $m\times n$ and $m < n$, and $A$ has rank $m$ (super important), then $AA^T$ is invertible, and $A^TA$ is not. (Invertibility $\iff$ full rank, and the rank of $A^TA$ = rank $AA^T$ = rank $A$.)

So ideally, if we're going to invert $A$ on the right side, then we need something like $B = A^T(AA^T)^{-1}$. (This is the unique right-inverse of $A$.) If $m \leq n$, then $AA^T$ is possibly invertible (if $A$ has rank $m$). If $m > n$, then it is not possibly invertible.